# Can I use the concept of 'tags' (derived from StackExchange sites) in a personal project?

Tags: tagging

I have a small personal project that I expect will be viewed by, at most, about 5 people. 'Tags', as used on this site and StackOverflow, would be helpful. Can I explicitly use something called a Tag in my personal project where the purpose/function is essentially the same?

Comment: Tagging is not a concept unique to SO.  Go for it.

Answer (score 3):

The Stack Exchange network has not invented tagging and has not patented their use.

Tag to your heart's content.